# Changing Color of Custom Icons in Navigation Drawer Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, navigation-drawer

I have been having trouble displaying images in the default navigation drawer, as they seem to still have the default gray color.

[Original Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn6Z1.png)

[Menu With Custom Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C656I.png)

Any suggestions on how I can make the navigation drawer display the actual colors of the images?

activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/a0279566532_10"
        android:title="Wallpapers" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Featured User Artwork" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon24"
        android:title="About" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon21"
        android:title="Send" />


</group>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use colored images rather than material images. This could be there simple solution

Answer (score 0):

put your icon in drawable file and use this in xml file!

To get a custom color image, either you download and use your own images, either you change icons colors in your xml file like this:

```
app:itemIconTint="#color"
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: what if my image uses more than one color?

Comment: It seems the gray color continues to stay. unless I add 
        app:itemIconTint="#color" however this option only allows me to choose one color.

Comment: the icons of the drawer can only have one type color so if your image is multicolored it will take the default color until you change this color for a

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has worked with navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); in the MainActivity.java!

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but i think somebody will benefit from my answer. In navigation view icons have default grey color and you can't change that in xml unless you want to set color for all icons in menu like this:

app:itemIconTint="@color/someColor"

Only solution that i have found is this:

```
    val navView : NavigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
    val normalDrawable : Drawable = navView.menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).icon
    val wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(normalDrawable)
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, resources.getColor(R.color.someColor))

    navView.menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).setIcon(wrapDrawable)
```

Here is the link to post that explains this in more depth: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-quick-tips-8-how-to-dynamically-tint-actionbar-menu-icons

Post is about action bar menu icons but this code works for navigation drawer icons also.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show the original color of all the icons, do this:

```
mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

If you want to show the original color of an specific icon, do this:

```
navigationView.getMenu()
            .findItem(R.id.your_item_id)
            .getIcon()
            .setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```